# Vite changes suddenly the way it compiles my Vue3 application files

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I am developing a Laravel application with frontend in Inertia + Vuejs.
Originally with version 9 of laravel I've installed the vite (v3.2) plugin and when running the production script it generated a js file for each vue file and that gave a very light and agile application.
Suddenly, after upgrading to Laravel 10, which shouldn't have any impact on the frontend, the production script started generating a single js file on build, which made the app much less performant.

I would like to know if the Laravel update determined the behavior change in Vite and if there is any way to go back to having the compilation of individual files without downgrading Laravel.

My vite config file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```